# Looking for a data structure with persistent sequential indexes

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure that works essentially like this:

- The structure is an ordered sequence of values.
- Each inserted value claims an index that is larger than the previous index, will not be reused and will not shift (it is *persistent*).
- All items before a particular index can be removed from the structure in one operation.
- All items that are still alive are reachable by their index.
- All items between two indexes can be retrieved in a batch. (If they could be retrieved while a new item is being added, that would also be great.)

The above is my best implementation guess. The properties I actually want are to be able to have a consumer which keeps a sort of bookmark value and can read the new items without missing out, and to be able to clear out items before a certain timestamp. However, the data structure need not know about the timestamp; being able to delete everything before a particular index is fine.

The way I would implement this structure is by keeping an int of where the item count starts and then keep either a list of items directly or a list of list segments. The index being some sort of primitive integer will wrap, but not within several multiples of the realistic timespan of the program's life.

The structure that I know of that gets closest is the particular ring buffer from [the LMAX Disruptor](http://lmax-exchange.github.com/disruptor/). However, that structure also blocks if the consumer gets too far behind which will not suit my purposes. The consumer is batch-oriented and may not get frequent CPU time; the Disruptor works best with dedicated logical tasks continuously working against the ring buffer.

So the questions I'm asking are:

- Is there a name for this?
- Is there an implementation of it for C# or another language?
- Is there a better alternative for my use case?

Answer (score 1):

Dont know of any preset collections that work exactly like that, but you  could create a custom collection object, extending System.Collections.CollectionBase.

```
public class MyCollection : CollectionBase
{
    public MyCollection() { }
```

This collection base object containse a List property that you can expose any way you like, for instance, add an Add() method

```
public int Add(Object o) // could by anything
{
    return List.Add(o);
}
```

You could have a GetRange(int start, int length) that returns a new collection, and just as you fill the return collection, remove from the base collection

Comment: +1, This is essentially what I will resort to if I don't find any other answers. I know that I will have some problems with reading a batch of items while adding a new item or clearing out some old items ("Collection was modified" concurrent enumeration and mutation), which is why I'm looking to see if the problem is already solved some other way.

Comment: If you're looking for indexes to stay the same even when the collection changes, you could explore using a Dictionary<Int32, Type> and let the persistent index be the "key" and the object value be the "value" of the dictionary pair

Comment: That was my first thought too, but wouldn't that be very inefficient in getting a range of values? Getting something out of a dictionary is constant, but it doesn't have to be fast. I guess my own usage guarantees me a contiguous range of values.

Comment: If you will always want a sequential range, then why the need for persistent indexes? The default enumerator for collections will adjust indices as the collection changes, but his does help to insure that you're items stay sequential, you can always do an insert at an index, pushing the above up. Also, if you end up with indices of high value, then have a cleaned out collection, but then copy out to an array using the highest index, you end up allocating way too much memory.

Comment: "The default enumerator for collections will adjust indices as the collection changes" - won't the default enumerator for most collections, or at least the enumerators for collections I would consider using as my own collection, throw horribly ("Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute") as soon as something is changed?

Comment: Also, if I have seven elements starting at 20000, I do not intend to actually allocate an array with space for 20007 elements. The whole point is to keep an int saying 20000 and some sort of internal list with those seven elements in the order inserted. Knowing that, I can arrange to retrieve the right item anyway.